# Cinnamon: Titlebar in panel?

Tags: panel, cinnamon

One thing I really liked about Unity is that the titlebar and buttons for windows were in the top panel, I was wondering if I could have that same effect in Cinnamon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this cannot be done with Cinnamon, at least not without a great amount of coding.

Cinnamon is a completely different desktop manager than Unity. A feature of Unity is that the application menu is included into the Panel. Cinnamon does not provide this feature. In Cinnamon, the Panel acts like the Panel in e.g. Windows 7.

Comment: Shucks, that may be a deal breaker! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As you know now there is difficult create in cinnamon, the same as the ubuntu devs do on unity. Thats is really true, but not impossible on free software. Anyone can reuse the code and put it on another language or platform. And this are actually done, but is increible that the most difficult thing is not write the code and functionalities. The difficult part is found how be compatible with other sessions and programs, when you try to do a similar things or/and functionality. The Appmenu (global menu) is an example of what occurs. Duplicate the modules, could cause conflict and will be for do the same. Reuse the current code is the most sane thing, because on my opinion is also a contribution to the same distro (in that case ubuntu), but well. The Appmenu need a patch for some subset of applications and this patch is private to the session (unity).

As another example, recently was renamed a package that was developed by ubuntu, but also was used on other ubuntu sessions and also on others distros. Now is called unity-gtk-module and have a patch to only be active on unity session, because it may cause problems with other sessions. The appmenu also need patch the gnome settings daemon to call dinamically some gtk properties. Again this ofcourse only occurs for unity session and can not be modify without create a duplication of the patch, and again with conflicts. Is possible and is the best, share ways to turn on/off the things. There are also mechanisms to do that actually but apparently not for all people and things... This is the history of the appmenu, but this not begin with unity or ubuntu (It was ubuntu, who put order into the gtk chaos). This occurs on several things and on several places and in my opinion is a shame.

https://github.com/lestcape/Global-AppMenu